# $ \alpha = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{n!}}$ transcendent over $\mathbb Q$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am working on a problem where I have to prove that a certain real number defined by an infinite series is transcendental over $  \mathbb{Q}$ The number is defined as follows:

$$
\alpha = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{n!}}.
$$

This number is the limit of the sequence of partial sums $ (\alpha_N)_{N \geq 1} $, where:

$$
\alpha_N = \sum_{n=0}^{N} \frac{1}{2^{n!}}.
$$

I am given that $ \alpha $ is assumed to be algebraic over $ \mathbb{Q} $, and that

$$
f = T^d + a_1T^{d-1} + \ldots + a_d \in \mathbb{Q}[T]
$$

is the minimal polynomial of $ \alpha $.

The task is broken down into several parts:

1. Given that $ D \geq 1 $ is a common denominator of the coefficients $ a_i $, which implies $ Da_i \in \mathbb{Z} $ for all $ 1 \leq i \leq d $, I need to show that:

$$
|f(\alpha_N)| \geq D^{-1}2^{-d \cdot N!}
$$

2. I have to prove that:

$$
0 < \alpha - \alpha_N < 2^{-1 \cdot (N+1)!}.
$$

3. It needs to be shown that there exists a constant $ C > 0 $ independent of $ N $ such that:

$$
|f(\alpha_N)| \leq C2^{-(N+1)!}.
$$

For this, there's a hint to write $ f $ as $ f = (T - \alpha)g $ in the polynomial ring $ \mathbb{R}[T] $.

4. Finally, I need to derive a contradiction and conclude that $\alpha$ is transcendental over $\mathbb{Q} $.

I'm not sure how to approach proving these inequalities or deriving the contradiction at the end. Any help or hints on how to proceed with any parts of this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not a proof but just an idea : in binary the increasing gaps between the zero's are not easily removable. Thus is it very unlikely an integer polynomial of it would give an integer. Perhaps working with " tails " of the number in binary will help.

Comment: This is a classic theorem. Such numbers are called Liouville numbers.

Comment: See this here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like an exercise given to you, so I will not give the full solution here.

1. Rather than directly showing $|f(\alpha_N)| \geq D^{-1}2^{-d\cdot N!}$ you should show $|D2^{d\cdot N!}f(\alpha_N)| \geq 1$.
2. I think this is technically wrong as stated. Note
   $$\alpha - \alpha_N = \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty 2^{-n!} \geq 2^{-(N+1)!}.$$
   But, you can show $\alpha - \alpha_N < 2^{-(N+1)!+1}$. After factoring out $2^{-(N+1)!}$, try to get the other factor to look like a more familiar infinite series. Don't worry about keeping the bound tight.
3. Using the hint, $$|f(\alpha_N)| = |\alpha_N-\alpha|\cdot|g(\alpha_N)| =  (\alpha-\alpha_N)|g(\alpha_N)| < 2^{-(N+1)!+1}|g(\alpha_N)|.$$ So it suffices to show that $|g(\alpha_N)|$ can be bounded by a constant that does not depend on $N$. Calculus/analysis gives you the tools to do this.
4. Finally, the contradiction is derived from the bounds from question 1 and 3.